# Constant p-value for all my tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, wilcoxon-signed-rank, scipy

I am comparing the performance of two AI models across 15 data sets. One model performs heavily better than the other on all the performance metrics.

When I perform a one-tailed Wilcoxon signed rank test, I am always getting a p-value equal to 3.0517578125e-05, no matter the performance metric I am using.

As an example, when I am testing on the accuracy metric, these are my samples:
accuracy of model A=[98,994,99,93.2,99.3,99,99.4,99.4,99.5,94.1,96,99.6,98.2,99.3,96.6]
Accuracy of model B=[88.4,97.9,96.4,66.9,97.5,98.8,96.3,96.7,97.7,87.2,81.8,97.7,95.2,97,95.8 ]

So model A is always outperforming model B. And this is happing for all the other metrics on all the other datasets.

Is this normal? Is this value some kind of threshold for the test? I am using the scipy library from Python if that makes a difference.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly are the data on which the Wilcoxon test is performed? (I don't mean the numbers, rather a precise description as I don't fully understand from your question what exactly you have done there.)

Comment: If you're ranking the outcome-differences across data sets, it's the smallest possible p-value you can get with the test. It would be observed whenever all the signs are the same. Are you doing one-sided tests?

Comment: @Glen_b Chances are you are right, but in principle, from the information in the description, it could also be the second or third smallest... even though admittely not very likely.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Christian for the pmf, yes, but not for p-values. `psignrank(0:2,15)` gives
`3.051758e-05 6.103516e-05 9.155273e-05` ... so the only p-value it works for is the most extreme, and even then, only one-tailed

Comment: @Glen_b Something about $2^{-15} = 3.0517578125\times 10^{-5}$ and there being $15$ datasets (with each, presumably, giving a machine learning performance metric that counts as a sample).

Comment: @Dave Presumably the pair-differences (difference of performance) on each data set is being ranked for the signed rank test. The most extreme result in one direction (all-negative or all-positive differences) will indeed have probability $2^{-15}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help .
I am doing a one-tailed wilcoxon test. 
When I am comparing for the accuracy matric for example, my samples are something like this:
accuracy of model A=[0.98,0.994,0.99,0.932,0.993,0.99,0.994,0.994,0.995,0.941,0.96,0.996,0.982,0.993,0.966]
Accuracy of model B=[0.884,0.979,0.964,0.669,0.975,0.988,0.963,0.967,0.977,0.872,0.818,0.977,0.952,0.97,0.958
]

I will modify the question and add this to make it easier to read

Comment: Yes, as I explained above, all the pair-differences have the same sign (naturally,  it must be in the direction you specified in the alternative).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Wilcoxon signed rank test operates on signed ranks, as the name implies. This means that your paired differences each get assigned a rank $R_i$ and a sign $s_i$. The rank of the $i$-th difference is simply where it would appear if you sorted your list of differences by their absolute size, with the smallest difference getting rank 1 and the largest difference getting rank $N$, where $N$ is your sample size. So in your case, your differences get numbered 1 to 15, and you also record each of their signs. The Wilcoxon test statistic is then computed as: $W=\sum_i s_i R_i$.

If model A is better than model B across all 15 datasets, then since all the differences will have the same sign (+1 or -1), this formula works out such that the test statistic will be 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 15 = 120 (or -120 but that makes no difference). And because you always convert your paired differences to these signed ranks, it doesn't matter what performance metric you started with: as long as model A outperforms model B 15 out of 15 times, the test statistic will equal 120.

And since the test statistic is always the same, so is the p-value.